# Structuring an array the correct way with lodash groupBy

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, lodash, javascript-objects

I have an object that looks like this:

```
{
    data: [
        { id: "1", state: "accepted", estimate_date: "2019-12-17" },
        { id: "2", state: "rejected", estimate_date: "2019-12-17" },
        { id: "3", state: "open", estimate_date: "2019-12-17" },
        { id: "4", state: "open", estimate_date: "2019-12-18" },
        { id: "5", state: "rejected", estimate_date: "2019-12-18" },
        { id: "6", state: "accepted", estimate_date: "2019-12-18" },
    ]
}
```

When I use lodash groupBy on the object like this:

```
const key = 'data';
const groupedEstimates = groupBy(estimateData[key], 'estimate_date');
```

It returns:

```
[
  [
    "2019-12-17"
  ],
  [
      [ { id: "1", state: "accepted" } ],
      [ { id: "2", state: "rejected" } ],
      [ { id: "3", state: "open" } ]
  ]
],

[
  [
    "2019-12-18"
  ],
  [
      [ { id: "4", state: "open" } ],
      [ { id: "5", state: "rejected" } ],
      [ { id: "6", state: "accepted" } ]
  ]
]
```

But now I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
[
  {
    date: "2019-12-17",
    items: [
      { id: "1", state: "accepted" },
      { id: "2", state: "rejected" },
      { id: "3", state: "open" },
    ]
  },
  {
    date: "2019-12-18",
    items: [
      { id: "4", state: "open" },
      { id: "5", state: "rejected" },
      { id: "6", state: "accepted" },
    ]
  }
]
```

Except I don't know how to achieve that using lodash. It doesn't have to use lodash but I only used that at the start as it seemed an easy solution to my problem. Now that I'm trying to achieve a more sensible data structure I would like some insights on how to achieve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After grouping by the `estimate_date` property, iterate the groups object with `_.map()`. Generate the group's object by taking the key (2nd param) for the `date` property, and mapping the `items` to omit the `estimate_date`:

```js
const estimateData = {"data":[{"id":"1","state":"accepted","estimate_date":"2019-12-17"},{"id":"2","state":"rejected","estimate_date":"2019-12-17"},{"id":"3","state":"open","estimate_date":"2019-12-17"},{"id":"4","state":"open","estimate_date":"2019-12-18"},{"id":"5","state":"rejected","estimate_date":"2019-12-18"},{"id":"6","state":"accepted","estimate_date":"2019-12-18"}]}

const groupedEstimates = _.map(
  _.groupBy(estimateData.data, 'estimate_date'),
  (items, date) => ({
    date,
    items: items.map(o => _.omit(o, 'estimate_date'))
  })
)

console.log(groupedEstimates)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: I had to change it to ``estimateData['data']`` or in my case ``estimateData[key]`` since I declared that already. 

The rest of your answer does exactly what I asked for though. Thank you.

Comment: It doesn't matter to the solution either way. That's why I've change - to reduce confusion. You're welcome :)